# There's no way ahead, we can't go ahead (AmE use)

Tags: word-usage

This is a description (I made it up myself).

So 4 people are running away from wolves. They reach the end of the cliff.

Can I use:

> They couldn't  go ahead.

Or:

> There was no way ahead.

And if one of them exclaims:

> Here is no way ahead.

Is the use of "ahead" natural? Does it mean that they can't "go any further"?

Answer (score 1):

"Ahead" sounds a little bit unnatural. You would be more likely to hear one of the following:

> There was no way forward.
>
> They could go no further.
>
> They couldn't go on.

As an exclamation, someone might shout:

> We can't go forward!
>
> There's nowhere to go!

Depending on the circumstances, someone might add:

> We have to turn back!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "they couldn't go ahead" or "there was no way ahead".

They both sound pretty natural to me, although I have to say "they couldn't go any further" sounds *more* natural to me. But I can't give you a reason why.

The phrase "here is no way ahead" is definitely *not* natural, although perhaps you mean "there is no way ahead".

On a separate note, most people would say "edge of a cliff" not "end of a cliff".

Comment: What I meant: We can't  go ahead. @fred2.

Comment: **"But I can't give you a reason why."** I will try to help. Standalone, the sentences are a little awkward, because something is missing. But they sound just right if you imagine a scream prior to those sentences: "Don't stop! **Go ahead!** The wolves are getting closer!" - My "scream" is not perfect, I am aware, but it should help get the idea. Now you know why you never read a book written by me :D